# Command 'scala' not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: scala

I downloaded scala,unpacked it and copied to `/usr/local/share`

After that,I edited ~/.bashrc

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/share/scala-2.12.8
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

Anyway,it does not work.

```
scala -version

Command 'scala' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install scala
```

I could go for apt install but I don't get it what is wrong.

```
/usr/local/share$ ll
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 јул  1 06:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root  4096 јун 23 18:04 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 апр 21 08:04 appdata/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 јун 25 21:03 applications/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 јул 25  2018 ca-certificates/
drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff 4096 јул 25  2018 emacs/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 јул 25  2018 fonts/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 апр 19 08:44 lua/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 јул 25  2018 man/
drwxrwxr-x  6 miki miki  4096 дец  4  2018 scala-2.12.8/
drwxrwsr-x  7 root staff 4096 мај 14 15:05 sgml/
drwxrwsr-x  6 root staff 4096 мај 14 15:05 xml/
```

Comment: You need to `export PATH=...` (probably `export SCALA_HOME=...` too).

Comment: Can you list the files inside `scala-2.12.8` as well?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `apt install`? Using the standard mechanisms is generally a good idea!

Comment: Yeah,I fixed with apt install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `.bashrc` won't affect an already open shell. You could explicitly source it (`source ~/.bashrc`) to have it take effect, or open a new shell to reload it.